# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

soy solo un aficionado a la programacion y como tal me estoy topando con cierto problema. El codigo a continuacion me da el siguiente error:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at computeCourses
```

Si ejecuto la función computeCourses() desde la consola de chrome si funciona y no entiendo por que, agradezco su atención.

```js
const urlJson = '../data/data.json'
let coursesRaw
let courses = []

const dataCohorts = () => {
  fetch(urlJson)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      coursesRaw = response
    })
}

dataCohorts()

let computeCourses = () => {
  for (var i=0; i < coursesRaw.length; i++){
    courses.push(coursesRaw[i].id)
  }
}
computeCourses()
```

Comment: Has probado inicializar let coursesRaw = 0;?

Comment: Hola Anthony, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que `fetch()` es una llamada asincrona.  Debes de esperar a que la llamada regrese para que la variable `courseRaw` sea definida.  Puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
const urlJson = '../data/data.json'
let coursesRaw
let courses = []

let computeCourses = () => {
  for (var i=0; i < coursesRaw.length; i++){
    courses.push(coursesRaw[i].id)
  }
}

const dataCohorts = () => {
  fetch(urlJson)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      coursesRaw = response
      computeCourses()
    })
}

dataCohorts()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono, leere mas sobre fetch.

Answer (score 1):

lo que dice el error: `coursesRaw` no tiene length por que es definida como  `undefined`,

`dataCohorts` puede llegar a darle valor a `coursesRaw`, pero como es un `fetch` que promete (en algún momento) hacerlo, `computeCourses` recibe la decepción de una promesa incumplida. O dicho de otra manera, se apresura y no espera.